# many to many field - django model - understanding

Tags: python, database, django, database-design, many-to-many

i am trying to implement small project where one person can add another person as a friend.

i want to model this relationship in database: i thought, i will do another model called `friendship` and i will write its model like this:

```
class friendship(models.Model):
  friend = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

is this all? i am somehow stuck in logic not knowing how to design this.. i read the doc but i am not coming to the point somehow, can someone please help me out.

thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219979/sql-best-practise-for-a-friendship-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't really need to create another model unless you need to store extra information on relation. For example, it defined the basic relationship already:

```
class User(models.Model):
  ...
  friends = models.ManyToManyField(self) # self means User.
```

If you want to store extra information, such as which kind of friends, how close they are. 
Then you need an extra models.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(self, through='Friendship')


class Friendship(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="from_user")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="to_user")
    friend_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    friend_rated = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: How is this different from using a Foreignkey as opposed to a ManyToMany relationship? Is it because the Freindship model contains Foriengkeys?