# Designing friend relationship

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Here's the problem I need to deal with:
I have a table `persons [ID, Name, LastName..]` . Now I need to save friendships among multiple users. I can't figure out any elegant and maintainable solution. Any ideas?

Comment: make a new table friendship, with two fields, friendof and friedID.

Comment: The `persons` table holds information about individuals. Now i need to save information about people how know each other. Let's say they meet each other on the trip.

Comment: If I got you correctly.. here are some duplicates http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10199/how-should-i-design-a-relationship-table-for-friendship 
.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009190/mysql-friends-table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379236/database-design-best-table-structure-for-capturing-the-user-friend-relationship 
&
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219979/sql-best-practise-for-a-friendship-table 
and trust me there are so many similar questions on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1(Recommended)**
- Table-persons with columns [ID, Name, LastName..]
- Table-Fiends with Columns [ID, P.ID]

**Solution 2**
- Table-persons with columns [ID, Name, LastName, FriendID(ID)] Self-Referencing column